# Is there a standard way to specify the type of a callback function in a docstring?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function which accepts a callback. Is there a standard way to document the type of this parameter?

```
def example(callback):
    """Example function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    callback : type
       Description of `callback`.
    """
    print(callback(3, 14))
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found the answer while formulating the question, but the question itself doesn't give any results on Google.

[PEP-0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#callable) introduces type annotation in python. For example the type of a callback function taking two integers and returning a string is:

```
from typing import Callable

Callable[[int, int], str]
```

Comment: How do I document that the function accepts optional `*args` and `**kwargs` parameters? I have a construct where a callback function can have case specific parameters that get passed through by the caller upon initialization. For instance: I create a Button class instance where the CB gets the button as first argument. The Button `__init__` however also accepts arbitrary `**kwargs` that are stored and passed through to the callback on the `click` event. How would I document that type of a callback?

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable "There is no syntax to indicate optional or keyword arguments; such function types are rarely used as callback types." Seems like there's no standard way to document those. Perhaps a better option would be to pass the click parameters as a dict in which case it's a fixed parameter.

Comment: Hmm... alternatively I might just say it's a `dict` type and describe it more thoroughly somewhere in the textual documentation. I was hoping that there was some pythonic way to do that.

Comment: The pythonic way would be to pass **kwargs as the dict itself. This way you're explicitly giving the callback the extra parameters. The problem with what you're trying to do is that you expose the internals of the callback where they shouldn't apparently be needed. Basically the function managing the callback would now need to know what parameters the callback needs/expects, whereas ideally the callback should be a black box that the managing function doesn't care about.

Comment: Oh that's how I do it. The kwargs is passed through to the callback as a dict when it is invoked. The calling function/class doesn't know nor care about what's inside the kwargs.

Comment: To clarify this: I have an `onclick_cb` and a `**kwargs` parameter in the `__init__` method of the Button class. The `kwargs` dict is stored in the Button instance as a `dict` and handed over to the callback like `self.onclick_cb(self, kwargs = self.cb_kwargs)` from inside the Button instance when the button is clicked. The first parameter is the Button instance itself and the rest depends on what is provided from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like that and while I think that callback should always be a function, AFAIK there's no way to specify the type of a function and I kept reusing callbacks with the same arguments doing different things so that's what I came up with.

```
import abc


class BaseCallback(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, param: int):
        self.param = param
        self.do_things()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_things(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError


class MyCallback(BaseCallback):
    def do_things(self):
        return self.param * 2


def func(callback: BaseCallback):  # type of callback specified
    callback()


func(callback=MyCallback)
```

You don't need to run the `do_things` method in init (imo it's ugly), depends on how much power do you have regarding where/when callback is run.